# Google Classroom Pub Sub push notifications encryption/decryption format

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-classroom

I have registered for receiving Google Classroom push notifications from Google Cloud Pub/Sub for my Google classroom class. I have registered for one of my specific classID. I am successfully able to receive notification every time student/teacher is added/removed in the class. But the data parameter which looks like holds the actual json for the delta seems to be encrypted. Does anyone know the encryption format and how I can change it and also if I can find more documentation for it.

The json that I received on my listener end point is like this-
(I have scrambled the data)-
{"message":{"attributes":{"registrationId":"-091231239109812309"},"data":"sadfuasoufyasufwehgsgdaHDFADAbnxznbnsF[WEIUPEQUYUWSDSFDJSFHLASLSFahdgsHasdhskjsdljhsdfsaX=","messageId":"4323240932612037","message_id":"4323240932612037","publishTime":"2018-05-09T05:28:13.948Z","publish_time":"2018-05-09T05:28:13.948Z"},"subscription":"projects/thisproject/subscriptions/thissubscription"}

Comment: Never mind. I got the answer. It is base 64 encoded. Would have been great if it was documented in the Google Classroom API Push notification documentation (https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/push-notifications) too along with the Google Cloud Pub Sub documentation (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publish-messages-to-a-topic).

Answer (score 1):

It is base 64 encoded. Not documented in Google documentation.

Comment: It is documented `message data must be base64-encoded` in the link you provided. https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publish-messages-to-a-topic Base64 encoding is so common in APIs ...